# Separate values of a column as diferrent columns as same query

Tags: sql

I have a table `UTENSILS` with 3 columns like this:

```
CLASS_NAME   RANGE    COUNT
---------------------------
pens         0-0.5     200
pencil       0-0.5      50
pens         0.5-1.0   300 
pencil       0.5-1.0    40
pens         1.0-1.5   150
pencil       1.0-1.5    45
```

I want a query that displays the above table result as below:

```
RANGE      Pens        Pencils
------------------------------
0-0.5       200          50
0.5-1.0     300          40
1.0-1.5     150          45
```

Any ideas about this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a pivot operation. We need database brand and version.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is known as a `PIVOT`. This is when you transform data from rows into columns.  Some databases have a `PIVOT` function that you can take advantage of but you did not specify which RDBMS.

If you do not have a `PIVOT` function then you can replicate the functionality using an aggregate function along with a `CASE` statement:

```
select `range`,
  sum(case when class_name = 'pens' then `count` end) pens,
  sum(case when class_name = 'pencil' then `count` end) pencils
from yourtable
group by `range`
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c366/2)

*Note: the backticks are for MySQL, if SQL Server then use a square bracket around `range` and `count`. These are used to escape the reserved words.*

If you are working in an RDBMS that has a `PIVOT` function, then you can use the following:

```
select *
from
(
  select class_name, [range], [count]
  from yourtable
) src
pivot
(
  sum([count])
  for class_name in ([pens], [pencil])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/894ba7/1)

Both will produce the same result:

```
|   RANGE | PENS | PENCIL |
---------------------------
|   0-0.5 |  200 |     50 |
| 0.5-1.0 |  300 |     40 |
| 1.0-1.5 |  150 |     45 |
```

The above will work great if you have a known number of values for `class_name`, if you do not then, depending on your RDBMS there are ways to generate a dynamic version of this query.

In SQL Server a dynamic version will be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(CLASS_NAME) 
                    from yourtable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [range], ' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select CLASS_NAME, [RANGE], [COUNT]
                from yourtable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum([COUNT])
                for CLASS_NAME in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/894ba7/3)

Answer (score 0):

This pivot query can be used in all major DBMS. The trick is getting the bad column names 'range' and 'count' quoted property.

SQL Server (below) uses `[]`, MySQL uses backticks (`), Oracle uses double quotes, SQLite can use any of the preceding.

```
  select [range],
         sum(case when class_name='pens' then [count] else 0 end) Pens,
         sum(case when class_name='pencil' then [count] else 0 end) Pencils
    from tbl
group by [range]
order by [range];
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the dynamic version of the pivot:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T

CREATE TABLE #T(
    [CLASS_NAME] VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    , [range] VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
    , [count] INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #T([CLASS_NAME], [range], [count]) VALUES ('pens', '0-0.5', '200')
INSERT INTO #T([CLASS_NAME], [range], [count]) VALUES ('pencil', '0-0.5', '50')
INSERT INTO #T([CLASS_NAME], [range], [count]) VALUES ('pens', '0.5-1.0', '300')
INSERT INTO #T([CLASS_NAME], [range], [count]) VALUES ('pencil', '0.5-1.0', '40')
INSERT INTO #T([CLASS_NAME], [range], [count]) VALUES ('pens', '1.0-1.5', '150')
INSERT INTO #T([CLASS_NAME], [range], [count]) VALUES ('pencil', '1.0-1.5', '45')

DECLARE @PivotColumnHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @PivotColumnHeaders = STUFF((
        --SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 PERCENT
        SELECT DISTINCT '],[' + [CLASS_NAME]
        FROM #T
        ORDER BY '],[' + [CLASS_NAME]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 2, '') + ']';

DECLARE @PivotTableSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @PivotTableSQL = N'
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM #T
  ) AS PivotData
  PIVOT (
    SUM([count])
    FOR [CLASS_NAME] IN (
      ' + @PivotColumnHeaders + '
    )
  ) AS PivotTable
'

EXECUTE(@PivotTableSQL)
```